# Alternative to contextClick in Chrome: Selenium-WebDriver- Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I know one can find similar question,but no one gave an alternate solution.Please bear with me.

After some research I realized it is not possible  to automate contextClick in Chrome browser.For ex:

If I need to perform below code and browser has to be Chrome-

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");

Actions ac= new Actions(driver);        

ac.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"))).contextClick().sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();
```

It would be helpful if I can get an alternative to using contextClick options.
Thanks

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do ?? what action ??

Answer (score 0):

On my chrome browser, contextClick is working fine. Try below line of code, it may resolve your problem.

ac.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"))).contextClick().sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do context click only, then

```
    Actions conClick=new Actions(driver);

    //i am expecting you are try to perform right click id = hplogo
    conClick.contextClick(driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"))).build().perform();

    // if you want to select or click any option in this context menu
    // go for click with specific location, no need of keys
    // if required use sleep before click
    driver.findElement(By.id("required location")).click();
```

if above click after context click is not working as expected, then you can also try below way

```
        Actions conClick1=new Actions(driver);
    //i am expecting you are try to perform right click id = hplogo
    //after context click moving to 25 vertically, may be second option in context menu and clicking
    conClick1.contextClick(driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"))).moveByOffset(5, 25).click().build().perform();
```

Thank You,
Murali